# How to get average of a node metric only for compute nodes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, prometheus, monitoring, promql

I would like to get average percentage of CPU usage, but only for compute (aka worker) nodes. That means I need to combine two metrics here. Individual problems are easy to solve.

To get average CPU usage percentage, I can use (cluster node is represented by `instance` label here):

```
sum(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle"}[5m])) / count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}) * 100
```

To get list of compute nodes (cluster node name is represented by `node` label here):

```
kube_node_role{role="worker"}
```

But how to put these two together?

Some time ago I have created a query that shows number of running pods per compute node:

```
count(kube_pod_info * on(node) group_left(role) kube_node_role{role="worker"} and on(pod, namespace) (kube_pod_status_phase{job="kube-state-metrics", phase="Running"} > 0))
```

so I assume I have to do something similar (using `group_left` again), but I'm to dull to actually do it :-/

Answer (score 1):

Uh, looks like it really helps to ask the question! Could this be the answer?

```
sum(
  rate(
    node_cpu_seconds_total{mode!="idle"}[5m]
  )
  *
  on(instance) group_left(role) label_replace(
    kube_node_role{role="worker"}, "instance", "$1", "node", "(.+)"
  )
) by (instance)

/

count(
  node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}
  *
  on(instance) group_left(role) label_replace(
    kube_node_role{role="worker"}, "instance", "$1", "node", "(.+)"
  )
) by (instance)

*

100
```

Any improvements on formatting this query also welcomed.